# How to configure minitest for performance and manually creating/removing fixtures

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, minitest

**My problems:**

- The customer database is in a machine over a VPN, so my tests are very slow (about 30-40 seconds each)
- This database is not entirely for my application and my data are related to the data that was already on the database
- Composite primary keys are present on the old database tables and the informix adapter does not support it for fixtures

**What I'm using:**

- Ruby on Rails 4.2.5
- Jruby 9.0.1.0
- Informix database via JDBC connection
- Minitest
- Minitest-reportes

**What I did so far:**

- The test time was decreased in 5-10 seconds with `Devise.stretches = 1` and `Rails.logger.level = 4` configs.
- I can't use fixture for the data that have relations with the tables that was in the system and have composite primary keys, so I built my own fixture methods for this tables, removing and creating objects at the first use and caching them in global variables after create to can be used without go to the database on next tests. This data I was inserting almost every test, so with this I could decrease the time a little more.
- Apparently rails fixtures was deleting and creating them all on every test, so I tried to disable use of transactional fixtures (`self.use_transactional_fixtures = false`) but apparently this does not change a thing.
- I need to reset "my fixtures" before the test suite and unfortunately rails fixtures are depending on them and when I'm trying to delete my data I'm getting some errors. Tried to drop "my fixtures" before creating rails fixtures with this code:

  ```
  class ActiveRecord::FixtureSet
    class << self
      alias :orig_create_fixtures :create_fixtures
    end

    def self.create_fixtures f_dir, fs_names, *args
      reset_cache

      #Deleting my fixture data
      People.delete_all

      orig_create_fixtures f_dir, fs_names, *args
    end
  end
  ```

The problem with the above code is `delete_all` is being executed on each test.

Besides the errors, I'm getting with all this fixture stuff, I reduced my tests time to about 8 seconds each.

**My test helper:**

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = "test"
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require "rails/test_help"
require 'minitest/autorun'
require 'minitest/reporters'

Minitest.backtrace_filter = Minitest::BacktraceFilter.new

# Load support files
Dir["#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/support/**/*.rb"].each { |f| require f }

ActiveSupport::TestCase.class_eval do
  extend MiniTest::Spec::DSL

  # Setup all fixtures in test/fixtures/*.yml for all tests in alphabetical order.
  fixtures :all

  self.use_transactional_fixtures = false

  Devise.stretches = 1
  Rails.logger.level = 4

  reporter_options = {color: true, slow_count: 5}
  Minitest::Reporters.use! [Minitest::Reporters::DefaultReporter.new(reporter_options)]
end
```

Can I do something better? Any clues to solve this problem with removing data? Any way to improve a little more my tests performance?

Comment: Have you considered using a CI platform? Is that a possibility?

Comment: Yes, but only this will not solve entirely my problem because even only testing the features I'm working on at the moment, still takes too long and gets a bit boring. What I´m really looking for is a way to speed up my tests in the scenario described. My fixture problems I solved now, I stopped using rails fixtures and handling the test data myself, 
improved the speed and I had no more problems.